Optimization of Offline maps in React native app
I am building a react native app and I want to include maps from openstreetmap. The area of the map is quite large, about 80000 km^2. Normally I would just use Google maps API/React Native maps, but these maps should work offline. My concern is data size and app speed.
One approach would be store map as images with coordinates of each corner, so a pins by coordinates could be easily added. Another way would be cleaning as much less important information from map, before adding it to a project.
Are there any other ways this could be achieved, while keeping small data size and quick app response?

i know that Mapbox GL offers something with vector tiles that are more efficient than images and they also have some offline features but i haven't used it personally
